# highcharts legend overlapping

Tags: highcharts, legend, overlapping

highcharts legend overlapping with the name section of the series.
I have got an url : [Issue example](http://jsbin.com/ubapaz/51/edit).

I want to place the legend text bellow the chart.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable floating parameter or use y parameter (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.y) to modify position.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, basically I had done a mistake in chart section..chart: {
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        } I have removed these fields and it worked..Also the floating stuff I have removed.